# In postgres, when transfering a schema to a role, the role still cannot access tables in that schema

Tags: postgresql

I want to grant a user full access to an **existing** schema. When I transfer ownership of a schema to that user, the user cannot access the tables.  Here is an example:

In the shell:

```
createdb test
psql -d test
```

In postgres:

```
create table table_a (
    code char(2)
);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 4.261 ms
create table table_b (
    code char(2)
);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 4.261 ms

create role user_b with login;

alter schema public owner to user_a;
```

Login to postgres as that other role:

```
psql -d test -U user_b
```

In postgres:

```
\dt
    List of relations
 Schema |  Name   | Type  | Owner
--------+---------+-------+--------
 public | table_a | table | doved
 public | table_b | table | doved

select * from table_a;
ERROR:  42501: permission denied for relation table_a

create table table_c (
    code char(2)
);

select * from table_c;
code
------
(0 rows)
```

user_b can create new tables in its schema, but not access existing ones in it (unless the tables' ownership was transfered).  Is there an easy way to grant that user full access to the schema, without having to go table by table via a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to user_a;
```

From the [grant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html) documentation.